# React Native - How to use .subscribe() with onLayout and onScroll of scrollview?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So I have a scrollview with components displaying the categories of food and drinks and onLayout of the "categories" I run this code to get their x and y values.

```
  _onLayoutCategories = ({ nativeEvent: { layout: { x, y, width, height } } }) => {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                categoryYvals: [...prevState.categoryYvals, y].sort(function (a, b) { return a - b })
            }))
    };
```

I also have another, horizontal scrollview to display only the category titles, and on layout of those, I run this code, still simply getting their coordinates and things like that

```
_onLayoutCatTitles = ({ nativeEvent: { layout: { x, y, width, height } } }) => {
        if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                catTitlesWidths: [...prevState.catTitlesWidths, width],
                catTitlesXvals: [...prevState.catTitlesXvals, x].sort(function (a, b) { return a - b }),
                catTitlesWidthsRef: [...prevState.catTitlesWidthsRef, { [x]: width }]
            }))
        }

    };
```

Now I do this so I can run this function when the categories scrollview is scrolled :

```
handleScroll = (event) => {
        var y = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y

        var translateValueX;
        var translateValueW;

        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.categoryYvals.length; i++) {
            if (y > this.state.categoryYvals[i] && y < this.state.categoryYvals[i + 1]) {
                translateValueX = this.state.catTitlesXvals[i];
                translateValueW = this.state.catTitlesWidths[i];
                    Animated.parallel([
                        Animated.timing(
                            this.state.translateX,
                            {
                                toValue: translateValueX,
                                duration: 75,
                            }
                        ),
                        Animated.timing(
                            this.state.translateWidth,
                            {
                                toValue: translateValueW,
                                duration: 50,
                            }
                        )
                    ]).start()
            }
        }
    }
```

Which in the end, produces this effect:
[image: Effect]

Now, it works fine when it is first mounted. However I get an error of "setstate on an unmounted component, this is a no-op and indicates a memory leak..." when I go back and navigate back to the screen (with React Navigation 5.x) and the onLayout functions are not called properly and `this.state.catTitlesValues` and `this.state.catTitlesWidths` are **empty** and cause an error when trying to animate.

How will I implement .subscribe() or promises to solve this?
Any help will be much appreciated, I need it. thank you in advance! :D

Components:

```
 <ScrollView stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} ref={(node) => this.scroll = node} onScroll={this.handleScroll} scrollEventThrottle={1}>
                           .................

                        <ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', borderBottomColor: 'orange', borderBottomWidth: 1 }}
                            horizontal={true}
                            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                            ref={(node) => this.scrollTitles = node}>
                            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', height: 50 }}>
                                {getCatTitles(this.props.route.params['menu'])}
                            </View>


                            <Animated.View style={[styles.highlight, { left: this.state.translateX, width: this.state.translateWidth }]}></Animated.View>

                        </ScrollView>
                    </View>


                    {DisplayMenu(this.props.route.params['menu'], this)}
```